Bounded-variable simplex method
Bounded-variable simplex method's algorithm

From $\textit{'Linear and Nonlinear
Optimization'}\ $ by Igor Griva; Stephen G. Nash
; Ariela Sofer; p.219
I'm not sure how $x_2$ is chosen as the entering variable; $x_1$ is currently $0$ but $\hat{c}_1 < 0$ whereas $x_2=u_2$ yet $\hat{c}_2 > 0$ so what does violating the 'optimality test' mean in the context and how are we able to quantify how large is the violation?

Notice that $x_N=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, that is at this solution $x_2=3$, the upperbound is attained.
When the upperbound is attained, if $\hat{c_2}>0$, then the optimality condition is not met.
In this case, both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are candidates for entering variables. The book choose the magnitude of the reduced cost as a criteria to select the entering variable. Since $|\hat{c}_2| > |\hat{c}_1|$, it is chosen.
